# controlling div with radio box cross frame

Tags: jquery, radio-button, frame

**edit:it worked problem was with name i passed wrong name(a space >_<)**

i have 4 div that have same id as my radio box both in diferent frame, when clicking on a radio box i want all div disapear (fadeOut) and the div with same id of my current radio box appear(fadeIn)  its  working with $("input[type=radio]")
but when using   $("input[type=radio][name=zone1_1]") it dont work

```
verif_check(id_check)//id_check is id of my the radiobox i clicked in
{ 
   $(document).ready(function(){

        $("input[type=radio][name=zone1_1]").each(function(){
            var id=$(this).attr("id"); 
            $(parent.droite.document).contents().find(id).fadeOut(); 
        });

        $(parent.droite.document).contents().find("#"+id_check).fadeIn();
    });
}
```

Comment: it looks like you are using iframes right ?

Comment: and whats with the wrapping curly brackets ? {...} ??? before $(document).ready() and after ;

Comment: @Val my jquery function is in a javascript one

Comment: a bit silly if you ask me, anyways have you tried `top.droite.document`? and I think `.contents()` has had some issues in the past with iframes, but I am not sure if they have fixed it on recent updates

Comment: @Val my code work if i deleted "[name=zone1_1]"

Comment: oh I see, well why dont u use the filter function then to add the name=zone_1_1 besides, why do you use type=radio when you know that names are unique is not like you will have checkboxes with name, the reason im asking is that you may not be able to have two attributes as filters :)

Answer (score 0):

IDs shoud be unique. I.e. no two elements should have the same ID. If you want to select multiple elements use the classname instead.

You code may not be foring because you are calling `find()` with the ID, not `#id`. The following will go some way to rectifying your problem:

```
$(parent.droite.document).contents().find('#'+id).fadeOut();
```

I'm also puzzled by the `verif_check(id_check)` wrapper. I would remove this.

Comment: my element are in different page(frame) so i dont have id problem

Comment: like i said it work without adding the attribure name here  $("input[type=radio])

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML then? Also try adding some code formatting in the main body of the first paragraph